# Can achieve Postgres jsonb LIKE query?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

does anyone know how to introduce wildcards (e.g. %% ) when querying a jsonb column that in this case is an array at the top level ? would also like to ignore casee

`select * from "food" where (type @> '"xyz"')`

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You need to unnest the array:

```
select f.*
from food f
where exists (select *
              from jsonb_array_elements_text(f.type) as x(typ)
              where x.typ like '%xyz%');
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be applying a `CROSS JOIN` between the table and unnested array elements without a subquery as

```
SELECT j.*
  FROM food f
 CROSS JOIN jsonb_array_elements(type) AS j
 WHERE value::text like '%"xyz"%'
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=37ebba2f6e7cf86e789cf0fca3f139cf)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

thanks folks.. this seems to do the trick:

````
SELECT *
  FROM 
      food,
      jsonb_array_elements(type) as types
  WHERE types::text ilike '%xyz%';```
````